# What is good lightweight GUI library that I can Embed within my application?

Tags: linux, mono, user-interface

I have developed a application in Mono.NET which is Console based application due to below requirements -

1. It should be less in size in terms of download.
2. It should be less dependent upon external libraries as much as possible.
3. It should be able to run on Text bases Linux GUI.

I am able to achieve this by Embedding Mono.NET framework. So my question is, is there any Light Weight UI library that I can use to give Good UI to my application? I know Winform is solution but It will failed on #3 above. I want something that I can embed with my distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by "lightweight", but we use XWT library, shipping it with our application. It's ~600KB after compilation.

You can find it on Mono's github: https://github.com/mono/xwt

It's more or less actively developed. Also it aims to have a native look on Windows, Mac and Linux (gtk).

There are some problems tough. If you need to have a very mature product that will allow you to do miracles with your gui, then XWT might show its limitations. Otherwise, give it a try.

Comment: My notion of lightweight means it should be self contain. I don't want to force user to download many external dependencies.